# JCA Connector Classloading

Tags: java, jboss, jca

in my Scenario, i try to use JCA Adapters to connect to an external storage - just to try this feature of J2EE.

I use JBoss EAP 7 and its packed implementation ironjacamar.

i deploy an `adapter.rar`, which contains an `adapter.jar` (this contains the `Connection` and `ConnectionFactory` Interfaces and all implementations) and `META-INF/ironjacamar.xml`.

I then deploy a `app.war` file, containing a Bean with an annotated field:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
...
     @Resource(lookup = "java:/eis/StorageConnectionFactory")
        private StorageConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
}
```

The war also contains the adapter.jar as library - as it needs to know of all the classes at runtime (NoClassDefFound etc.)

To my amazement, the Connector itself seems to work - as is get the Exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set conn.StorageConnectionFactoryImpl field Bean.connectionFactory to conn.HsmConnectionFactoryImp

and on ommitting the interfaces even:

```
 @Resource(lookup = "java:/eis/StorageConnectionFactory")
    private StorageConnectionFactoryImpl connectionFactory;
```

still

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set conn.StorageConnectionFactoryImpl field Bean.connectionFactory to conn.HsmConnectionFactoryImp
```

I see that the Problem is, that the adapter.rar does nto share the same classloader as the app.war and both contain the corresponding classes, leading to a sort of ClassCastException - how do i solve this issue correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't configure resource adapter properly.

See the below guide, it will help you to configure:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/version-7.0/configuration-guide/#configuring_jca_subsystem